# Add SQL Server Level Login in master Database using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure-sql-database, visual-studio, continuous-integration

I'm trying to add sever login in Azure SQL Server using Visual Studio 2019 SQL Project with SSDT and deploy it using Azure Devops by building CICD pipeline. The rest database object (e.g. tables, sprocs, external data sources, external tables, etc) created successfully except database logins.

My database project already had security folder that include login scripts (since i'm importing from existing database). The problem is, in order to add a server login, you must to add it to master databases and my CICD pipeline line set to non master database.

How do I add sever login to Azure SQL database using VS2019 and CICD via Azure Devops?

Comment: Have you thought about using contained logins?

Comment: Have a look a this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004439/how-should-i-handle-users-in-database-projects)